# What uses a docker container port?

Tags: networking, network-share, docker

While setting up my first `docker` environment, I created a specific network:

```
root@srv /e/docker# docker network inspect docker
[
    {
        "Name": "docker",
        "Id": "7b20560b36032d36ffe6c0ebece6b4408355d207f4e203a2957b0434ee0afdc1",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "10.200.0.0/24"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Containers": {},
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

I created a container from an image for this network with a specific IP:

```
root@srv /e/docker# docker create --network docker --ip 10.200.0.2 --hostname dev -p 22:22 --name dev base
807f3892241d314d20837c4c749912097e1f34c62884401acd9a06e201cb5876
```

I then started this container and got:

```
root@srv /e/docker# docker start dev
Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint dev (807f3892241d314d20837c4c749912097e1f34c62884401acd9a06e201cb5876): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:22: bind: address already in use
Error: failed to start containers: dev
```

Indeed, it has `supervisord` starting `sshd -D` which by default binds to all available IP addresses **for that host**. Since its IP is `10.200.0.2`, I expected `sshd` to bind to its `127.0.0.1` and `10.200.0.2`. It looks like this port is taken by something but what?

**The host does have an `sshd` running but that should not matter for the guest container, right?** (since it lives in its own world which konws only the two IPs above)?

**EDIT** after comments: In other words, I would like `sshd` to bind to the IP of the container (the one it sees = `10.200.0.2`) and to have this port exposed outside of the container, on the same IP. Or, in practical terms, I would like to be able, from the host, to `ssh root@10.200.0.2` and reach the `sshd` of the container.

Comment: I'm confused, why are you trying to expose port 22 to the docker guest, it's only running the process you start in the container, which shouldn't be sshd

Comment: @JacobEvans: I have `sshd` running in the container. i would like it to bind to the IP of the container (the one it sees = `10.200.0.2`) and to have this port exposed outside of the container, on the same IP. In other words, I would like to be able, from the host, to `ssh root@10.200.0.2` and reach the `sshd` of the container.

Comment: @JacobEvans: I updated my question to clarify what I want to achieve.

Comment: then you don't need to publish the port, publishing the port does a 1:1 NAT to the host IP, by default from the host you can ssh to any service port on the container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't publish the port if you want to connect locally.

`/e/docker# docker create --network docker --ip 10.200.0.2 --hostname dev --name dev base`

You want to expose the port.
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

test/DockerFile

```
FROM base
EXPOSE 22
```

`docker build -t test -f test/DockerFile test/DockerFile`

Answer (score 0):

Try amending the `-p publish` param to bind to a specific IP, for example `-p 10.200.0.2:22:22`. By default docker publishes the exposed port to 0.0.0.0 if I recall correctly. And as you mentioned, you already have port 22 in-use on the host network.

Answer (score 0):

So, the `-p` flag publishes the port on the host. Just exclude the tag for using it on the container network only.